# Show related nodes of category selected in current node (using static select list)

Tags: nodes, views

I created a content type containing a select list field (ie Fruit, Food, Jewelery etc).

I am not using any node reference nor any taxonomy vocabulary.

I have added a static select list. I want to show related nodes under the current node. I.e if I visit a node containing the *fruit* category, then all the other nodes containing fruit category should be shown below the current node.

Comment: so, you want a dynamically loaded reference field, but without using a reference module?  You need to either use a Taxonomy and use the built in systems, or use node reference , entity reference or some other reference module (even if you write your own) to accomplish this

Comment: i know it is possible and also easy to accomplish this task with taxononmy terms or with node reference but i clearly mentioned in my question that i am using static select list. I just want to do with this select list.

Comment: and I'm saying that's not possible based on how your question is worded

Comment: no it could be complex but not impossible, as i am trying to do tihs and iam sure i will get the solution soon

Comment: you want to dynamically reference nodes, without using anything to reference the nodes, contrib or custom. That's like saying I want to drive a car, but it can't involve a car when I do it...

Comment: the reference is present there but in the form of select list

Comment: I don't think you understand how referencing works. Where the reference is held is irrelevant, be it a ist, or check boxes, or what have you. You still need a module (contrib or custom) to reference each of those elements to the related nodes. The only other way I can think of doing it would be through jS and an AJAX call based on the selection - but that would just be a JS version of a PHP module that eseentially does the same thing

Comment: listen carefully that i want the same functionality like taxonomy reference or node reference. But the case is that i am not using these two reference i am just using refernece of select list instead of them. do you understand???

Comment: yes I do, I don't believe you understand how referencing dynamic content works though...

Comment: my dear you can believe that i understand how referencing works but in currrent case it is not working

Comment: if it's not working darling, then perhaps that should have been your question, not how do I reference nodes without using a referencing module as your question is currently worded...

Comment: my dear the question is not as you worded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your persistence on not using taxonomy is interesting . any way to make it happen you will need to use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) , create a view of type content pane , add a contextual filter , filter your content based on your field , then you will need an argument for your filter , in the pane settings you will find a argument setting , pass your content field as argument , then in page manager in node view add your created pane . (don't forget to restrict node view to your content type)
Check [The views Context](https://drupalize.me/videos/views-context?p=1147) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend converting your select list field to Taxonomy and use a module like [Similar By Terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/similarterms).

> This Drupal module attempts to provide context for content items by
>   displaying a block with links to other similar content. Similarity is
>   based on the taxonomy terms assigned to content. Blocks are available
>   based on similarity within each of the defined vocabularies for a site
>   as well as a block for similarity within all vocabularies.

Comment: your suggestion is good but this is used with taxonomy terms and i am not using taxonomy. So not the solution of my problem.

Comment: @WaQaRAli any reason why you aren't using Taxonomy? I could be wrong since I don't know how your site is set up and all sites are different but if you are trying to get related nodes it sounds like you should be using Taxonomy.  It may be more work to fix but this now but if you do you will be taking advantage of Drupal's robust taxonomy system.  If updating to taxonomy isn't an option then you will need to create a custom module and create a custom block that runs a query to get the related nodes.

Comment: the only reason here is that i already have been used taxonomy for this purpose and that also works for me but now i want to do the same thing by using static select list.